# Reading file doesn't work in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to open a file but it is displaying nothing.

```
openf = open('C:\Python27\NEWS', 'r')
openf.read()
```

It is neither displaying text nor any error. What could be the reason?

and when i write like this

```
openf = open('C:\Users\K\Desktop\wait.txt', 'r')
>>> print openf
```

This gives Output:

```
<open file 'C:\\Users\\K\\Desktop\\wai.txt', mode 'r' at 0x0000000002B4DDB0>
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

`read` doesn't display anything - it merely returns a string. If you're not at an interactive prompt, the only output you will see is what you print.

```
openf = open('C:\Python27\NEWS', 'r')
print openf.read()
```

`print openf` will give details about the `openf` object. It's an open file pointed at that file name, it was opened in "read" mode, and it exists in memory at address 0x0000000002B4DDB0.

Comment: then how to display the contents of file

Comment: It is not displaying anything, though my file has content

Comment: Works on my machine. Are you doing anything else in your script that you haven't mentioned here?

Comment: it worked now.. I have one more doubt, What type of files we can read?

Comment: Any kind of file. The extension makes no difference.